# Isn't this question exactly what EL&U is for?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/a-tricky-serial-semi-colon) is fascinating, but I think it's clearly EL&U and not Writers.  Am I correct that this is off-topic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we should leave it here.

Sending the question to English will doubtless produce all manner of interesting technical answers. (I don't see any serial semicolon questions over on English, so unless it's buried in another question there, I don't think it would be a duplicate there.)

However, if Lauren wants to expand the question to include the context of the work around the text cited, that would be a question that's okay here. (As in a readability/style question or even a small critique. I for one would love to see more tech writing critique questions here, but that would be a slightly different kind of question.)

I personally am fine with questions that can potentially exist on this site or on English. (Or even on both; if Lauren would like to get more into the mechanics of the grammar involved, EL&U would br great for that.) There's significant overlap between the two sites.

However, in the end, it's all about **what's best for the question**. Does the answer have more to do with readability and how to write? Then it's better off on Writers. However, if it's more concerned with what's grammatically and mechanically correct, than it'd get better answers on English.

Comment: I will do so if you can explain the reason. Why is the context important to this particular question?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - You already did explain it in the comments; Corporate email and corporate brochure text. That gives it context. Good point, though; upon reflection, I'm editing this answer.

Comment: This is more about readability, I think, than strictly about grammar. I know the grammar involved and I know how to reword it so there's no grammar issue -- I am concerned with making it read smoothly.

Comment: Then I think it makes more sense here. (This meta thread will also be a great reference for similar borderline cases in the future.)

Comment: Based on this conversation, have significantly edited this answer. Summary: @justkt raises some great points, but I think the question is fine here.

Comment: Great answer.  According to SE itself you can actually post a "cross-site duplicate" without problems if one wants the answers from both EL&U and here, also.

Answer (score 2):

As I just put in a comment reply:

@justkt - I think it falls between the two somewhat. It is about the appropriate way of writing this - a writing style question - while the focus is on a punctuation mark - a punctuation question. If we treat it as writing style "how can I show this list correctly and clearly", not what the rules strictly say, it works better here. For an answer about "what do the rules say we should do", EL&U would be better

The context of this question means I think it fits better here